# What is the main difference between node group and cell in IBM web sphere?

Tags: websphere

What is the main difference between **node group** and **cell** in IBM web sphere?

Answer (score 1):

**Cell** is a logical grouping of nodes that enables common administative activities in a WebSphere Application Server distributed environment. A cell can have one or many clusters.

**Node** is a logical group of one or more application servers on a physical computer. The node name is unique within the cell. A node name usually is identical to the host name for the computer. That is, a node usually corresponds to a physical computer system with a distinct IP address.

**Node group** is a collection of managed nodes. Managed nodes are WebSphere® Application Server nodes. A node group defines a boundary for server cluster formation.